# sprintf(): scaning only the first value in float array

Tags: c

Can I convert float array to string?I dont care if the dot would be as a string value. i just need to separate the numbers into string.

so far I have done this

```
void H(float *suma, int k){
int i=0;
char str[200]  = "";

    sprintf(str, "%.2f", *suma);


for(i=0;i<strlen(suma);i++) {
    printf("%c", str[i]);
}
}
```

but it keeps converting only the 1st value in my float array.I hope I made it clear. If not here is an example of my problem.

```
array[0]= 123.45;
array[1]= 543.21;
```

but i need it as

```
  string[0]='1';
  string[1]='2';
  string[2]='3';
  string[3]='.';
  string[4]='4';
  string[5]='5';
  string[6]='5';
  string[7]='4';
```

etc...

Comment: @hmjd I just wanted to print that string. I thaught it gives me exact number of characters in array.. but I think i am wrong otherwise you wouldn't ask..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to print the list of all array numbers in their string format here is the solution (I have assumed k is the length of float array):

```
void H(float *suma, int k){
    int i=0, j;
    char str[200]  = "";

    for(j=0;j<k;j++){
        sprintf(str, "%.2f", *(suma+j));
        for(i=0;str[i]!='\0';i++) {
            printf("%c\n", str[i]);
        }
    }
}
```

You can use strcat() to concatenate strings if you want all of them in a single string.

Comment: you are unbelievable smart! This is exactly what I need!

Comment: Glad to know I was of your help.

Answer (score 1):

Here's a solution:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

void H(float *suma, int k)
{
    int i,j;
    char str[200]  = "";
    for(j=0; j<k; j++)
    {
        sprintf(str, "%.2f", suma[j]);

        for(i=0;i<strlen(str);i++)
        {
            printf("%c", str[i]);
        }
        printf("\n");
    }
}

int main ()
{
    float b[]={123.432,213.432,12.2,31.3,13.4};
    H(b,5);
    system("pause");
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Does this work when I have for example 5 float numbers in my suma array ?